# Multiple Python3 Installations on OSX

Tags: python, macos

I have a machine with OSX 10.11.4 El Capitan. It comes with a default python3 installation. When I do

```
which python3
```

It returns

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
```

Now, I want to install some packages via pip. When I did a

```
pip --version
```

and then a

```
pip3 --version
```

both returned paths to python2.

So I installed python3 via homebrew. Now I installed scipy, with

```
pip install scipy
```

And when I do `pip freeze`, I can see it. But when I do an

```
import scipy
```

within `python3`, it gives me an `import error`. It probably links itself to the brew's `python3`. Now there are two ways out of this:

1. Uninstall brew's Python3 and keep system default and get pip for it. HOW?
2. Make brew's python3 default

How can I do any of these? Is there a more elegant way out? I do not prefer pyenv.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that you install with the proper version of pip by running `python3 -m pip` rather than just `pip3` or `pip`.

For example, on my Mac:

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
$ python -m pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

I have 3 different versions of Python installed, so to be sure that I'm installing packages to the right version I use the `python3 -m pip` trick.